# File browse CCK field

Tags: 7, entities, navigation, media

Is there a CCK field where I can add a link to a file, not an upload but something that will save the link as a URI.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: ok I have an image cck field and I want to attach a link to it - the file is one of 10 previously uploaded files so I would like to just select the file via a file browser and then in the node tempalate convert the uri to a link and wrap it around the image.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the above details to your post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [IMCE for FileField](https://www.drupal.org/project/imce_filefield) module. I've tested this module and working fine. It seems this is the module what you're looking for

> IMCE for FileField allows users to select files from IMCE File Browser. It supports FTP uploaded files by automatically registering them as IMCE files thus making them usable in a FileField.

**Step-1:**

Go to your filefield settings and Enable 'Allow users to select files from IMCE File Browsers for this field

[image]

**Step-2:**

Go you Manage Display settings of your content type and select FORMAT as URL to file

[image]

**Step-3:**

In node add / node edit form you can browse the *previously uploaded files* (from server) by clicking on 'Open File Browser' link.

[image]

So the file link will be displayed at node output for the uploaded file.